# Upload generated .apk into Diawi using script

Tags: android, apk, diawi

Is it possible to avoid manually uploading the .apk file into [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) by using some scripts?
I saw that there is a plugin for [Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/diawi-upload/) that uploads the .apk after CI and I was wondering if it is possible to do the same locally by using the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing in the Diawi documentation I found some guidance [here](https://dashboard.diawi.com/docs/apis/upload). But I had issues with the HTTP 2 version and I had to force curl to use HTTP 1.1 instead. You can open the terminal of the Android Studio a just write the scripts. With the `gradlew assembleRelease` a .apk file will be generated, and after that, the `curl` command will upload it to your Diawi profile.

This is the command for Mac users:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease && curl -v --http1.1  https://upload.diawi.com/ -F token='<your_DIAWI_token>' -F file=@/<path_to_your_apk>/myapp-release.apk -F find_by_udid=0 -F callback_emails='<your_mail>'
```

This is for Windows users:

```
gradlew assembleRelease && curl -v --http1.1  https://upload.diawi.com/ -F token="<your_DIAWI_token>" -F file=@/<path_to_your_apk>/myapp-release.apk -F find_by_udid=0 -F callback_emails="<your_mail>"
```